# Render other element in panel when children hit each other

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a custom panel that renders like a canvas renders it's children. I would like that 2 elements that hit each other (ie. touch each other somewhere) get replaced by another control that allows custom rendering of these elements near each other and for example puts them in a context menu.

I have code that can correctly detect these hits, however, I cannot seem to replace the elements by other elements, as the panel is always drawing the items in InternalChildren array.

I cannot do this hit testing before they get to the panel. As they come from a view that can be grouped and due to zooming in and out (which effects the positions/sizes of the children), won't know which elements collide until measuring of the panel happens.

Is there any way to let the panel render other elements than those that are in the InternalChildren array?

EDIT: image

http://www.imagedump.nl/img827/2849/12unled.png

Note that I do not care if block C get's replaced by another component or not, so if replacing it with a merged block is easier (which I think it will be), do so.

Comment: Honestly its s little difficult for me to understand your description... probably you may post some code and / or screenshot of what you are doing and / or expecting?

Comment: I have added an image here: http://www.imagedump.nl/img827/2849/12unled.png